# Ubuntu 15.10: multiple monitors do not work within VMware

Tags: vmware, 15.10

I have upgraded Ubuntu 15.04 to Ubuntu 15.10. Since then, I cannot use two monitors. Ubuntu runs as a guest OS in VMware.

I get the error message that the VMware tools need to be installed. I've reinstalled the VMWare tools but that does not help.

Has anybody solved this issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the same issue, but solved it by removing the vmware-tools, and installing open-vm-tools:

```
sudo vmware-uninstall-tools.pl
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

and then rebooting.  Hope that helps.

Comment: thx a lot Stephan :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is vmware has yet to update their tools. I've spent about 3 days worth of time on this and still haven't resolved the issue. My best advise is to revert to a snapshot previous to you're upgrading to 15.10. That or try to revert the upgrade with the package manager.

Comment: thx. for your feedback. Let's keep this thread open until there is a solution available

Answer (score 0):

For me (at least in 16.04) the solution was to run:

- `sudo apt-get purge open-vm-tools*`
- (*Ignore other threads saying to manually install kernel 4.6*)
- Get VMware to mount the media with the VMWare Tools installer stuff
- Extract the `.tar.gz` into `~/.` or somewhere read/write (*pointlessly ridiculous that vmware installer is in a read-only medium preventing installation from within*)
- (*even more hilariously ridiculous that the scripts at the base of their mount don't work or do anything*)
- `cd` into that extracted folder and run
- `sudo vmware-install.pl` and just say `yes` for everything
- Reboot

I've tried the `open-vm-tools` approach and it didn't work for any advanced VMWare feature but this does.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS and had the same problem.

I did:

```
    sudo apt-get purge open-vm-tools*
    sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

I think the upgrade did not went well. With this method you get a fresh install of open-vm-tools-desktop and all dependencies. And now it's working.