# Multiple Monitors while running Ubuntu on VM Ware, with Windows Host

Tags: windows, 16.04

I've re-installed VM Ware Tools (following instructions from here [Ubuntu 15.10: multiple monitors do not work within VMware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693794/ubuntu-15-10-multiple-monitors-do-not-work-within-vmware)). I've also tried following this https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-E51CADFC-31C3-491F-92D9-C9C1D9615668.html

but no luck. Please let me know if there is anything else I can try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With VMWare Fusion

> Click View > Use All Displays in Full Screen if Use Single Display in
>   Full Screen Mode is enabled.

on the VMWare Fusion menu, as indicated in the [documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.fusion.help.doc%2FGUID-0F5976E2-110E-4F59-85FB-1E430B317C91.html).

After that, all the displays should be available to configure in *Settings > Displays* in Ubuntu. You don't have to restart Ubuntu, it can be done while it is open.

If you have three screens, I suggest starting with the Ubuntu window in the middle, as it failed to detect the middle monitor on my first try.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an issue with Ubuntu 16.04 in particular. I switched to 14.04 and dual monitor now works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in ubuntu [open-vm-tools](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/open-vm-tools/+bug/1547858) in combination with ubuntu 16.04. Vmware did notice the issue in the release notes of vmware [player](http://pubs.vmware.com/Release_Notes/en/workstation/12player/player-1211-release-notes.html) and workstation.

I have tried several things but without luck. Reverting back to 14.04 seems to be the only solution at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Kernel 4.6.0 did the trick for me.

My Setup:
Ubuntu 16.04 guest with Open VM Tools installed, running on VMWare Workstation 10.0.7

**Update**

Spoke too soon. 4.6.0 brings it's own problem, which is that I can't cycle back to a single monitor. However downgrading the kernel to 4.3.6 as discussed [here](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/74), seem to be have fixed the issue.